# Cannot find module '@typescript-eslint/utils/ts-eslint' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-eslint

I'm working on a Nodejs typescript project, that I want to add a database connection to. I added the packages `mysql2` and `sequelize`, but ever since I added these two packages, I get the following two errors when I try to compile the project:

```
.yarn/__virtual__/@typescript-eslint-eslint-plugin-virtual-bd67eac881/3/.yarn/berry/cache/@typescript-eslint-eslint-plugin-npm-6.19.0-e459327339-10c0.zip/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/index.d.ts:1:36 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@typescript-eslint/utils/ts-eslint' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import type { ClassicConfig } from '@typescript-eslint/utils/ts-eslint';
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

.yarn/__virtual__/@typescript-eslint-eslint-plugin-virtual-bd67eac881/3/.yarn/berry/cache/@typescript-eslint-eslint-plugin-npm-6.19.0-e459327339-10c0.zip/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/rules.d.ts:38:33 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@typescript-eslint/utils/ts-eslint' or its corresponding type declarations.

38 import type { RuleModule } from '@typescript-eslint/utils/ts-eslint';
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have researched these errors and found out that they are intended behaviour and that I should set the `moduleResolution` of my tsconfig.json to `bundler`, `node16`, or `nodenext`. However when I do that, it forces me to update the whole project to ES Modules, which then forces me to update a ton of imports. I really want to avoid that for now (unless there is no other way, of course). My question now is: is there a way to fix this issue without changing to ES Modules?

This is my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

The `type` field in my package.json is set to `commonjs` and I did not change anything except for adding the following to my `dependencies`:

```json
"mysql2": "^3.7.1",
"sequelize": "^6.35.2",
```

I'm using Node v21.1.0, yarn 4.0.1 as a package manager and typescript version 5.2.2.

It's also absolutely possible that I didn't configure my tsconfig.json correctly, so please feel free to correct anything in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

To use "import", change your config:

```
"module": "ESNext"
```

Also post your package.json here to see how you are resolving modules. It should look similar to:

```
//package.json
{
  "name": "index",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-an-es6-import-in-node-js/